# make migration errors in symfony

Tags: symfony

i created a symfony project, did the create:database command (worked), after that i did the make:entity command (worked) and after that i wanted to run the make:migration command as it was shown to me. (Next: When you're ready, create a migration with symfony console make:migration). It throws me these errors:

In ExceptionConverter.php line 117:

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'check_constraints' in infor
mation_schema

In Exception.php line 28:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'check_constraints' in information_schema

In Statement.php line 130:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'check_constraints' in information_schema

can someone help me? in the information_schema is no such table as check_constraints ..

tried to clear the cache

Comment: Your migration should not touch any of the mysql system databases. Remove those from the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using database which you have. If you're using `mysql` then there are two configurations of it in `.env` file. Try using the one which does not have mariaDB in it.

Use this

```ini
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:3306/app?serverVersion=8.0.32&charset=utf8mb4"
```

Instead of following,

```ini
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:3306/app?serverVersion=10.11.2-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4"
```